# Hibernate inheritance : how to know the subclass returned by query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I use Hibernate and 3.6 and Spring Data JPA 1.5. I have an upper class :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Mother{

private long id;

// constructor, others attributes and accessors
}

@Entity
public class FirstSubClass extends Mother{

private String specificFirstSubClassNotNull;
// constructor, others attributes and accessors
}

@Entity
public class SecondSubClass extends Mother{

private String specificSecondSubClassNotNull;
// constructor, others attributes and accessors
}
```

I use spring data jpa to fetch data from database and i want to get all Mother object. I am able to fetch data from data. Spring data jpa return me a list of mother (List mothers. So i want to know which is the best solution to know which subclass is ?
Is it the first solution :

```
for(Mother mother : mothers){
if(mother instanceof FirstSubClass){
System.out.println("This is a FirstSubClass instance");
}else if(mother instanceof SecondSubClass){
System.out.println("This is a SecondSubClassinstance");
}
```

}

Or the second solution:

```
for(Mother mother : mothers){
if(mother.getSpecificFirstSubClassNotNull!=null){
System.out.println("This is a FirstSubClass instance");
}else if(getSpecificSecondSubClassNotNull!=null){
System.out.println("This is a SecondSubClassinstance");
}
```

}

I don't think the above are good. What would you do ? Any proposition are welcomed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The need of down-casting to apply a certain behaviour is a code-smell. After all you use inheritance for a very good reason, therefore you should take advantage of what OOP has to offer: **polymorphism**.

Your domain model don't have to be anaemic one-to-one mirrors of their associated database tables. You can add domain logic to your Entities and that's how you can apply type-specific behaviour.

Let's say you have the following hierarchy:

```
public class Mother {   

    @Transient
    public String getNickName() {
        return "Mama " + this.name;
    } 

}   

public class GrandMother extends Mother {   

    @Transient
    @Override
    public String getNickName() {
        return "Grandma " + this.name;
    } 

}   

public class GreatGrandMother extends GrandMother { 

    @Transient
    @Override
    public String getNickName() {
        return "Greatma " + this.name;
    } 

}
```

when you fetch a list of Mother entities, you can simply call the base class method and rely on polymorphism for specific type behaviour:

```
List<Mother> mothers = ...
for(Mother mother : mothers) {        
     LOGGER.info(mother.getNickName());    
}
```

Comment: but what if the subclass has extra fields that don't exist in the parent one, which is logical, and you need for example to access the getters of this subclass for these specific fields